# Solution check requested for showing a group $G$ being acted on by a finite field and turning it into a vector space.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, modules, abelian-groups

[image]

I have some questions from an exercise which is from the book [Module Theory
An Approach to Linear Algebra pg 7](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Module_Theory/iADvAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=modules%20an%20approach%20to%20linear%20algebra) I attached a screenshot of the question since the book cannot be Google books previewed,
Also, I am wondering if someone can check if my attempted solution is correct with respect to how I am interpreting the exercise.

The exercise question is as follows:

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group.  If $G$ has $m$ elements show that
>
> $(\forall n, t\in Z)$ $n\equiv t$ $(mod$ $m)$ $\Rightarrow$ $(\forall g\in G)$ $ng=tg.$
>
> Deduce that $G$ is a $Z/mZ$-module under external law $Z/mZ \times G \rightarrow G$ given by $(n/mZ,g)\mapsto ng$.  Conclude that every finite abelian group whose order is a prime $p$ can be regarded as a vector space over a field of $p$ elements.

I can either go with an additive or a multiplicative notation.   I am guessing it would be the same in either case, so I am going with the additive notation.

To show the first part of the question: if for any $g\in G$ and $G$ is of order $m$ and choosing $g$ as a generator for $G$, $gm=0_{G}, $ with $0_{G}$ serving as the identity element in $G$.  If $n, t\in Z/mZ$, $n\equiv t$ $(mod$ $m)$, then $n-t=mk$ for some $k\in Z,$  Hence $g(n-t)=g(mk)=(gm)k={0_{G}}k=0_{G} $ which gives $g(n-t)=0_{G}$ Because $G$ is abelian, we have  $ng=tg$

To show that $(n/mZ,g)\mapsto ng$ is a $Z/mZ$-module, we need to show that the map $ng$ satisfies the four axioms for a module.  So
if $\lambda \in Z/mZ$ and for any $a, b \in G$, $\lambda(a+_{m}b)=\lambda a +_{m} \lambda b$.  If $w \in Z/mZ$ also, then $(\lambda +_{m} w)x=\lambda m +_{m} wx$.  Also, $\lambda (wx)=(\lambda w)x $.  Since $1_{Z/mZ}$ is the identity element for $Z/mZ$, which gives $1_{Z/mZ} x=x$

For the last portion of the question, we need to show that the action $(n/mZ,g)\mapsto ng$ satisfies all the axioms of vector spaces are satisfied.

So if $x$, $y$, $v$ are $\in G$ and $n/pZ$ as a field since $p$ is a prime,

Associativity of vector addition, we have
With $n=1_{Z/pZ}\in n/pZ$, $x+_{p}(v+_{p}y)=(x+_{p}v)+_{p}y$

Commutativity of vector addition
$v+_{p}x=v+_{p}x$

Identity element of vector addition
The zero vector $0_{G}$ for $G$ is the identity element for $G$ since for $v\in G$, $v+_{p}0_{G}=v$

The additive inverse of vector addition can be found from the identity element of vector addition, so for every $v\in G $
$v+_{p}(1_{Z/mZ})v=0_{G}$

for multiplication of scalar with field elements
we have if $a$, $b$ are in $n/pZ$ and $v\in G$. then $a(bv)=(ab)v$

The identity element for scalar multiplication
$1_{Z/pZ}v=v$, for $v\in G$

For distributivity of scalar and field addition, we have
$a(v+_{p}x)=av+_{p}ax$ and $(a+_{p}b)v=av+_{p}bv$ with $a$, $b$ $\in n/pZ$, and $v$, $y$ $\in G$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: @Shaun I typed out the question.

Comment: That's better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since a vector space is just a module where the ring is a field, the second part follows immediately from the first.

Comment: is the solution for the first part ok??